# How can I play next mp3 file in directory?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm writing a script to loop through songs in my directory every 15 seconds. So far I have it set up to find an .mp3 file and play it for 15 seconds. How would I loop it to play a ***different*** .mp3 once the 15 seconds are up?

```
import os
import pygame

for filename in os.listdir("/mydirectory"):
    if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
        file = filename

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
pygame.mixer.music.play(,15.0)

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(): 
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(15000)
    if pygame.time.delay(15000):
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this to load the list of files:

```
files = []
file_index = 0
for filename in os.listdir("/mydirectory"):
    if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
        files.append(filename)
# files.sort() # do this if you want them in name order

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(files[file_index])
pygame.mixer.music.play(15.0)
```

Then use this:

```
file_index = (file_index + 1) % len(files)
pygame.mixer.music.load(files[file_index])
pygame.mixer.music.play(15.0)
```

to play the next file in the directory.

Comment: I was able to get it running correctly with your help. Thanks!